# Conservation of momentum in inelastic collisions

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, energy-conservation, conservation-laws, collision

if energy is not conserved in inelastic collisions(eg two ball collision), the energy can be lost as heat or sound, but won't the sound or heat cause the air molecules to move so the molecules also acquire momentum? Then how can momentum be conserved? or do the net momentum of the two balls system decrease?

Comment: Expand your definition of the system.

Comment: exclude the air, just the two balls

Comment: " but won't the sound or heat cause the air molecules to move so the molecules also acquire momentum?" - How can you say you are excluding the air if you are taking it into account?

Comment: uhm, I think what I meant is: there are energy lost out of the system(two ball) as heat, wouldn't the momentum lost to outside the system as well as the energy causes the objects outside the two ball system to move

Comment: Which objects outside the two-ball system?

Comment: like the ground, or the air? but I'm going to exclude resistance forces

Comment: You have to get your thinking straight. You cant tell us you are excluding the air and then suggest that the air will be moved by the two-ball system.

Comment: uhm, okay, what if it's in a vacuum and two balls collide and some energy is lost to deform the objects, then the energy caused the atoms in the ball to move, which wouldn't contribute to the macroscopic movement of the ball, then there are some momentum lost?

Comment: How is that momentum lost if it stays within the ball?

Comment: Wouldn't it be lost when we do the calculation macroscopically? like the momentum is still there but we don't take it to account when we do a typical collision problem, so we will overestimate the momentum that contributes to the velocity macroscopically

Comment: When we do a typical collision problem, we assume that bodies do not have internal structure. For All intents and purposes they can be assumed to be point particles of a certain mass.

Comment: then where will the energy be lost to?

Comment: In real world energy is lost to heat and other irreversible internal processes within the balls and/or surrounding medium. If you are solving a problem from a textbook, it should state what assumptions you can make. Generally, the assumptions will simplify the problem and make it solvable.

Comment: okay, thank you so much, I guess it's just the problem being incomplete then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a question of scale.
If the linear momentum changes during a collision due to the production of sound that change in linear momentum will be very much smaller than the total linear momentum of the colliding bodies.

In an inelastic collision the kinetic energy decreases due to the work done to permanently deform the colliding bodies and in the generation of heat and sound.

The sound waves will be generated in all directions so the net momentum change to the colliding bodies would be very small because the **net** linear momentum of the sound waves is so small.
The heat and permanent deformation is generated by internal processes involving internal forces within the colliding bodies and so the net linear momentum of the bodies will not change.
Just because bits of a body are moving around internally does not matter as it is the motion of the centre of mass of the body which is important.

Answer (score 1):

Microscopically, energy and momentum is conserved even at inelastic collisions. In the energy conservation law you have to incorporate potential energies $V$ due to the binding forces inside the colliding bodies. This potential energy is given by the sum over all single intermolecular/interatomic interactions.

In quantum mechanics, you have also the conservation of energy and momentum up to an uncertainty $\Delta p \geq \frac{\hbar}{2 \Delta x}, \Delta E \geq \frac{\hbar}{2 \Delta t}$. This uncertainty becomes relevant on very tiny length and space scales $\Delta x, \Delta t$.

Comment: thank you for the reply, I'm actually not at the level of understanding any quantum mechanics yet. So does the momentum of the two balls got lost to the surrounding?

Comment: Yes, it gets lost to the surrounding

Comment: okay thank you, so bascially I am still in high school, so if a question goes like this: a 5kg ball with 2ms-1 strikes an 10 kg ball at rest, and the collision is inelastic, after the collision, the total momentum of the 5kg ball and 10 kg ball will be slightly less than 10 Ns?